# GraphQL Filter on Enum Column

Tags: graphql, strapi

Below is my GraphQL Query to Fetch Posts from Strapi backend.

Please note I am running this on my Nuxt app.

Now I want to bring only those posts which have `post_status = "Publish"`

`post_status` is a ENUM field with two option as Draft and Publish

```
query GetPosts{
  posts {
    id
    post_title
    post_excerpt
    post_featured_image{url}
    post_content
    post_category{category_name}
    postingredients{ingredient{ingredient_name}, ingredient_unit}
    updated_at
    post_author{username}
    post_slug    

  }
  }
```

I did not understand how can I get

1. How to bring `post_status` values on my original Query
2. How to filter on the `post_status` where I can get only Published posts.

   ```
   query GetStatusEnum{      
       __type(name: "ENUM_POST_POST_STATUS") {
       name
       enumValues {
         name
       } }          }
   ```

Result of the above:

```
{
  "data": {
    "__type": {
      "name": "ENUM_POST_POST_STATUS",
      "enumValues": [
        {
          "name": "Publish"
        },
        {
          "name": "Draft"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add your `post_status` in your original request you just have to add it in the list of the attributes you want to fetch.

```
{
  posts {
    id
    post_title
    post_status <- here /!\
  }
}
```

Here is the query to fetch **Posts** that have `Publish` as `post_status`

```
{
  posts(where: { post_status: "Publish" }) {
    id
    post_title,
    post_status
  }
}
```

You can play with GraphQL playground in your strapi application:

http://localhost:1337/graphql

You will see in the right of you page a `docs` button that will show you all the information you need to create your GraphQL request.

Comment: unfortunately that won't work. Even I was thinking it will be easy. Below is the error you get. 

"message": "Expected a value of type \"ENUM_POST_POST_STATUS\" but received: \"2\"",

Comment: Hum weird, I created a fresh new app and it works well.
But I'm not sure to follow the query you are trying to do... your 2. point.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar scenario (though I'm using a Prisma layer as well so keep that in mind) and i'm not sure that you can filter for enum values on the call but you can filter what it returns.

```
const posts = [the array of all posts]

const isPublished = (post) => {
    if (post.post_status.includes('Publish')) {
        return post;
    }
}

let publishedPosts = posts.filter(isPublished);

return publishedPosts;
```